# How do I find IIS web application dependencies using Powershell and webadministration on Server 2012?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis, powershell, windows-server-2012-r2

Wondering if someone can help with this.

I have a number of servers that host IIS 7.5 and IIS 8.5 web application of various types.  As these are production web applications and servers i can't install any software on the server so i must find a way to remotely interrogate the server to retrieve the windows feature dependencies per web application.

I am aware already the I can use msdeploy to get the dependencies but that means i need to install the msdeploy software on the server which I cant do.

Also I am aware that I can use the Get-OSFeature to remotely retrieve the Windows features that are installed on a particular server.  This also is not useful as i need to connect to the web application to get the dependencies of the application.

So can this be done using powershell and `Get-WebConfiguration` and if so can someone show me as i have so far only been able to get the installed features using this method also eg.

```
Get-WebConfiguration system.webServer/* 'IIS:\sites' -Recurse
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are happy with **msdeploy**, you can just use it without installing it.

Create a temporary folder on the server, find an existing installation on Web Deploy 3.5 and copy the files from:

```
C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3
```

You can skip all the language folders you don't need.

Navigate into your new directory as elevated admin and just use `msdeploy.exe`.

When done, just delete the folder.